# A new result on the Diophantine equation $x^3 + y^3 +z^3 = 3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, diophantine-equations, journals, advice

The above Diophantine equation is unknown to have any further integer solutions other than $(x, y, z) = (1, 1, 1)$ and $(4, 4, -5)$.

I am a prospective undergraduate mathematics student in Zimbabwe and I recently obtained a new result that the above equation indeed has no further integer solutions such that $ \frac{1}{3} (x + y + z)$ is a perfect square.

I also came up with a new and surprisingly elegant elementary proof of the Erdos-Moser conjecture for odd exponents that the Diophantine equation:

$1^n + 2^n + \cdots + m^n = (m+1)^n$ has no integer solutions other than the trivial solution $1+2=3$ if $n$ is odd.

So which journal is best for me to submit my findings ? I was thinking of the Journal of Number Theory ? Also, i'm intending to apply for undergraduate admission in U.S.A / U.K, how can these results strengthen my admission prospects ? And which universities are most interested (or most suitable for) in undergraduate applicants who already have done some research before. ?

Comment: By far the hardest thing will be for you to convince a professional to look at your work. Unfortuntely statistics work against you, as there are many non-professionals who come up with badly written work claiming to do something amazing. For a professional it is almost surely a waste of time to spend time on such matters. Since you've already proved to be a bright young mathematician, you stand a chance. Make sure that whatever you send is written like standard mathematics, and make sure you provide a short summary of the proof idea, nobody will wade through 50 pages of unmotivated text.

Comment: I expect that the OP has seen now-deleted comments. The upshot was some (but not all) mathematicians are put off by phrases like "surprisingly elegant" to describe one's own work, which the OP might like to take into consideration.

Comment: I've rolled back an edit by the user @goodwill who seems to be the same user as the OP, not to mention other accounts

Comment: @YemonChoi, i don't appreciate you toying around with my post. The edit i made was personal and had nothing to do with the mathematical content of the question. Also, it is allowed to have two accounts which can be merged, and those happen to be my ONLY accounts. If for some reason you believe otherwise, that's not my problem and i don't have to convince you.

Comment: If you don't want other users editing your posts, ABD, then you've come to the wrong place. This website *depends* on experienced users carrying out editing tasks. And, yes, it is allowed to have more than one account, but only if they don't interact with each other. E.g., using one account to comment on posts where the other account is involved is very much frowned upon.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, i have no problem with any user editing my post, as long as the edit is relevant and necessary ! And i've never *commented* on posts involving one account of mine using the other account.

Comment: OK, ABD, but your goodwill account did make an edit on this question of yours. That's cutting it thin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My opinion is:
**Step 1**.
Repeat the arguments you use in your proofs again and again.
If you are still sure that you have some new (valid) things to say about the equation then go to
**Step 2**.
Learn how to use [LaTeX](http://arxiv.org/) ,write your paper and submit it to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/).
If it is submitted, then go to
**Step 3**.
Choose a journal which has previously published papers related to the equation you mention and submit it for publication.
(Don't choose the best journal but a serious one)

It would be better if you choose a title which won't make the editor think that he will probably waste the time of the referees.
A title "Some notes on the equation $x^3 +y^3+z^3=3$"  will be safer.

Good luck!!!

Comment: Thank you so much Konstantinos for your response. However, on submitting to arXiv, from my researches, it seems quite difficult to find an endorser ?

Answer (score 12):

Your phrasing in the second paragraph is a bit odd, I guess you mean that the equation "has no integer solution *such that* $\frac13(x+y+z)$ is a perfect square" (rather than "if"). If I am stressing this, it is because if you submit a paper to any decent research journal as you plan to, it must look completely professional or you face the risk to be dismissed.

You should probably have someone inside academia have a look at your paper and suggest improvement, if you have any one qualified who would be willing to spend some time helping you. If you are afraid of your ideas being stolen (which is in general not something to be afraid of in such a situation), disclose your work publicly or to several different person, so as to establish your paternity. In some cases it is however better to first get advice before public disclosure, as it might avoid embarassment if there is something very wrong in your work.

Then, to your question: I feel that your work, if right and not already present in one form or another in the literature, might be publishable. However Journal of Number Theory seems too selective for your results. Previous relevant papers are :

Zhou, Guo Fu; Kang, Chi Ding "On the Diophantine equation $\sum_1^m k^n=(m+1)^n$" J. Math. Res. Exposition 3 (1983), no. 4, 47–48.

Sondow, Jonathan; MacMillan, Kieren
Reducing the Erdős-Moser equation $1^n+2^n+\dots+k^n=(k+1)^n$ modulo $k$ and $k^2$. Integers 11 (2011), A34, 8 pp.

Moree, Pieter(D-MPI)
Moser's mathemagical work on the equation $1^k+2^k+\dots+(m−1)^k=m^k$. 
Rocky Mountain J. Math. 43 (2013), no. 5, 1707–1737

Gallot, Yves; Moree, Pieter(D-MPI); Zudilin, Wadim(5-NEWC-SMP)
The Erdős-Moser equation $1^k+2^k+\dots+(m−1)^k=m^k$ revisited using continued fractions.
Math. Comp. 80 (2011), no. 274, 1221–1237.

Urbanowicz, Jerzy(PL-PAN)
Remarks on the equation $1^k+2^k+\dots+(x−1)^k=x^k$.
Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Indag. Math. 50 (1988), no. 3, 343–348.

E.g. Integers or the Rocky Mountain journal are usually more accessible than JNT, but I cannot say for sure whether your work would be suitable there, as a general principle and because I know so little about it. [Involve](http://msp.org/involve/about/journal/about.html) might be a good match, and more inclined to handle properly submissions from people outside academia like you.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej and Benoit for your enlightening responses. I would also like to know how these results can increase my chances of gaining undergraduate (freshman) admission in U.K / U.S.A, so that i pursue my lifetime passion under the best possible training ?

Comment: @Tatenda: sorry, I forgot about this part. I never worked in the US, but I think that managing to publish a genuine paper in a serious mathematical journal, however lesser it can be on the scale of glamor, is quite an achievement at your stage and will be regarded as such. No need to try to aim the highest journals, just do it right.